# Is it worth having a redirect for rasberrypi.stackexchange.com?

Tags: feature-request

I've got this wrong several times, and all I got was a panda...

**UPDATE** updated the title to avoid confusion, sorry if that renders some comments obsolete

Comment: For commedy value, see http://raspberrypi.se (exactly as given above). Isn't .se the TLD for Sweden?

Comment: I don't understand this question. A redirect from where?

Comment: @Jivings rasberry -> rasPberry

Comment: @Benjol: I see, is this a common mistake?

Comment: @Jivings, no idea.

Comment: Haha, just wondering why you thought of this?!

Comment: Would we need to allow for 2 typos? eg `rasberypi.stac...`. Maybe 3. Could end up at hundreds of registered subdomains.

Comment: You mean you haven't set it as your browser homepage?

Answer (score 1):

It would be a subdomain on StackExchange.com, so I assume the mods/devs would be able to configure it.

I would expect they wouldn't want to as that sort of thing could snowball fairly quickly if it was done for all SE sites.

Additionally - if you get it wrong a lot you could always change your own config to redirect that address.

Comment: I wasn't thinking of me, just that it's a mistake that people could easily make and assume that this site doesn't even exist. (

Answer (score -1):

If possible, then why not? But the url is not available, unless you own it?

Comment: It would be a subdomain - we wouldn't need to own it.

Comment: Jon, I was assuming it was *intended* to use the TLD .se. That is what I would prefer, actually. But it is already owned, apparently.

Comment: I think he abbreviated the SE bit. The typo is the missing "p" in raspberrypi